# Use Variable as Value

Tags: powershell, variables, key, hashtable

I have a question because I can't use Variable as values on hashtable on PowerShell.

I have two variables.

1. To get the UserPrincipalName from AD and add to `$alias`

   ```
   $alias = (Get-ADUser -Server "Add Server" -filter * -SearchBase "Add OU").userprincipalname
   ```
2. Then with the `$alias` I need to get the mailbox quota with `Get-Mailbox` and `Get-MailboxStatistics` in MB and make a percentage

   ```
   $mailbox = foreach ($user in $alias) {
       ($user | Get-MailboxStatistics |
           Select-Object @{name="TotalItemSize (MB)"; expression={
               [Math]::Round(($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split("(")[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(",","")/1MB),2)
           }})."TotalItemSize (MB)"
   }
   ```

   - Using this max. quota (100 GB on MB)

     ```
     $maxquota = 102400
     ```
   - To get the %

     ```
     $totalsize = foreach ($size in $mailbox) { 
         (($size * 100) / $maxquota)
     }
     ```

   Example of MailboxSize

   ```
   PS> $totalsize
   2.43220703125
   14.3363671875
   8.875205078125
   5.032177734375
   15.548349609375
   0.0112109375
   ```
3. Then I want to make a hash table with `$alias` and `$totalsize`

   ```
   $test = foreach ($name in $alias) {
       foreach($total in $totalsize){}
       @{$name = $total}
   }
   ```
4. The result should be

   Key - Name in `$alias`
   Value - Percentage in `$total`

   For example:

   ```
   David  - 4.50
   Juan   - 15.00
   Moises - 50
   ```

But when I test the hashtable I'm just receiving each name with all the values or all the names only with the first value

How can I get all the values like a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in step 3 would not create a hashtable, but an array of hashtables. Also, it wouldn't know which mailbox size belongs to which user, because that information is lost after step 2.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$test = @{}   # create new empty hashtable

foreach ($user in $alias) {
    $size = Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $user |
            Select-Object @{n='TotalItemSize (MB)';e={...}} |
            Select-Object -Expand 'TotalItemSize (MB)'

    $test[$user] = ($size * 100) / $maxquota
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `$Test` as an array of hashtables. Assign your `$Hashtable` and then add values to it with the `Add` method:

```
Param (
    $maxquota = 102400
)

$HashTable = @{}

$alias = (Get-ADUser -Server "Add Server" -filter * -SearchBase "Add OU").userprincipalname
$mailbox = Foreach ($user in $alias) {($user | Get-MailboxStatistics |  Select-Object @{name="TotalItemSize (MB)"; expression={[math]::Round(($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split("(")[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(",","")/1MB),2)}})."TotalItemSize (MB)"}
$totalsize = foreach ($size in $mailbox) { 
    (($size * 100) / $maxquota)
}

$test = Foreach($name in $alias){
    $HashTable.Add($Name,$totalsize)
}
```